# Scientific Programming Stack for Clojure

Tags: clojure, scipy, scientific-computing

I currently use Python for most of my programming, but I'm interested in learning Clojure. What libraries do I need to reproduce the functionality I have with scipy, numpy, and matplotlib? Is there anything like the Enthought distribution?

Comment: Look for similar libraries in Java, and call them from Clojure.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Start with Incanter: http://incanter.org/

Then look at Java scientific libraries.

Answer (score 2):

I'll second Stuart's answer - Incanter is great.

As of 2013, it's also worth looking at [core.matrix](https://github.com/mikera/matrix-api), which provides a high performance NumPy/SciPy API for matrix/vector maths to Clojure. The medium term plan is to get Incanter and core.matrix working together seamlessly.